# How do I resubmit a form with a POST request after addressing a timed-out session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, http, session, timeout

Let me see if I can explain this.

I have a `before_filter :require_user` in all of my controllers.

In my ApplicationController I have the following method

```
def require_user
  unless current_user #Redirect to login page if no user currently logged in
    flash[:notice] = "You must be logged in to access this page"
    redirect_to login_path
  end
  if current_user.timed_out? #Redirect to login page if user's session timed out and set session[:return_to]
    session[:user_id] = nil
    session[:return_to] = request.request_uri
    flash[:notice] = "Your session has timed out, please log back in"
    redirect_to login_path and return
  end
  current_user.update_last_request_at #Otherwise user is logged in. Update last request time in user model
end
```

Then I use the following method in my SessionsController to redirect back to the page the user wanted if they were logging back in after a time out.

```
def redirect_back_or_default
  session[:return_to] ? redirect_to(session[:return_to]) : redirect_to(root_path)
  session[:return_to] = nil
end
```

All pretty standard stuff - probably all copied from railscasts or somewhere like that, I can't remember exactly.

The problem I have encountered is when a user brings up a form and then the session times out before they submit it. When they submit it, a POST request is sent to the app and the before_filter intercepts things and requires them to log back in. At this point things go wrong as a GET request is sent by the `redirect_to(session[:return_to])`. Is there a way of capturing the request method (and the form parameters ideally) so these can be forwarded in the session?

Comment: This question is pretty old. Did you ever find an answer to it?

Comment: Nope, and I can't remember how I worked around it either sorry.

Comment: I'm interesting if anyone can comment on whether it's good practice to ever automatically resubmit a post/put call.  In our current project we've got an automated javascript form to resubmit after a login ... feels messy ...

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question you can do it, but its painful.

```
session[:return_to] = {controller: params[:controller], action: params[:action], id: params[:id]}
session[:return_to_params] = parameters.inspect
```

Then to get them usable again

```
eval(session[:return_to_params])
```

Then to redirect and re-issue

```
redirect_to(params[:return_to].merge(eval(session[:return_to_params])))
```

You can make this as complicated as you'd like from storing it in the DB, their session, writing it to a file, etc.

---

I'd like to recommend an alternative

First change your submission to be an ajax request.  If your worried about your form not redirecting after create, just have your create method respond with javascript of:

```
window.location = "<%= destination %>"
```

Then modify your require_user to be similar to this:

```
def require_user
  if current_user.nil? || current_user.timed_out?
    if request.xhr?
      render('ajax_login')
    else
      #what you were doing with your login requests
    end
  else
    current_user.update_last_request_at
  end
end
```

I set this up on a rails 2.3 but its easy enough to translate over.

Basically if they submit an ajax request and are logged out, you respond with javascript which creates an overlay with a login screen.  If they successfully sign in, you remove the overlay and they can click submit again (or you submit it yourself with javascript if that's what your looking for).